# using fragment instead of activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I relatively new to Android and I'm stuck on this stupid issue for quite a while now:

Part of the application I'm currently working on has a `GridView` of images, and once you click on an image it opens on full screen. Normally I would open the full screen image on a new `Activity`, but my instructor asked me to do it on a `Fragment`.

Even though I read many fragments guides and saw many fragments examples over the last few days, I still don't understand how to make the new `Fragment` open instead of (or on top of) the original one.

More explicitly, I don't understand where should I put the xml view of the full screen image.
I could really use a simple code sample on how to open a new fragment on the whole screen.

Comment: You just need to make your original view into a fragment, your second view into a fragment,  and navigate between them with a fragment transaction.  If you want to split hairs,  you should tell him that custom viewgroups are more stable and easier to animate,  and fragments are unnecessary. :p